# How to make GestureDetector detect three-finger drag in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, gesturedetector

I would like to find a way to drag an object using three fingers in flutter. I am new to flutter but I understand how to use GestureDetector. The outcome can just be dragging a square around the screen using 3 fingers (nothing must happen when 2 fingers are used). Can anyone help me?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11600) might help.

Answer (score 1):

Not a perfect solution but you can leverage [ImmediateMultiDragGestureRecognizer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/gestures/ImmediateMultiDragGestureRecognizer-class.html)

Basically we would be using `RawGestureDetector` and use mentioned gesture recognizer to have all the touch events we can. Since there can multiple touch events we would be saving the number of taps and use it to make a draggable component in Positioned widget.

First we need to add RawGestureDetector

```dart
          RawGestureDetector(
            gestures: <Type, GestureRecognizerFactory>{
              ImmediateMultiDragGestureRecognizer:
                  GestureRecognizerFactoryWithHandlers<
                          ImmediateMultiDragGestureRecognizer>(
                      () => ImmediateMultiDragGestureRecognizer(),
                      (ImmediateMultiDragGestureRecognizer instance) {
                instance.onStart = (Offset offset) {
                  //We are getting all touch points here, we just need to manage them
              }),
            },
          ),
```

Now we need to manage all those raw touch points, to do that we can create certain callbacks and classes which will help us to store/manage them by extending [Drag](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/gestures/Drag-class.html) class, as we must return Drag event in onStart Callback.

Complete code would be :

```dart
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  TouchCallbacks touchCallbacks = TouchCallbacks();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(touchCallbacks.taps.length.toString()),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            left: touchCallbacks.taps.length == 3
                ? touchCallbacks.taps.first.offset.dx
                : 200,
            top: touchCallbacks.taps.length == 3
                ? touchCallbacks.taps.first.offset.dy
                : 200,
            child: Container(
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          ),
          RawGestureDetector(
            gestures: <Type, GestureRecognizerFactory>{
              ImmediateMultiDragGestureRecognizer:
                  GestureRecognizerFactoryWithHandlers<
                          ImmediateMultiDragGestureRecognizer>(
                      () => ImmediateMultiDragGestureRecognizer(),
                      (ImmediateMultiDragGestureRecognizer instance) {
                instance.onStart = (Offset offset) {
                  setState(() {
                    _counter++;
                    touchCallbacks.touchBegan(TouchData(_counter, offset));
                  });
                  return ItemDrag((details, tId) {
                    setState(() {
                      touchCallbacks
                          .touchMoved(TouchData(tId, details.globalPosition));
                    });
                  }, (details, tId) {
                    touchCallbacks
                        .touchEnded(TouchData(tId, const Offset(0, 0)));
                  }, (tId) {
                    touchCallbacks
                        .touchCanceled(TouchData(tId, const Offset(0, 0)));
                  }, _counter);
                };
              }),
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// Just saving the taps information here
class TouchCallbacks {
  List<TouchData> taps = []; //list that holds ongoing taps or drags
  void touchBegan(TouchData touch) {
    taps.add(touch);
    //touch began code here
  }

  void touchMoved(TouchData touch) {
    for (int i = 0; i < taps.length; i++) {
      if (taps[i].touchId == touch.touchId) {
        taps[i] = touch;
        break;
      }
    }
    //touch moved code here
  }

  void touchCanceled(TouchData touch) {
    //touch canceled code here
    taps.removeWhere((element) => element.touchId == touch.touchId);
  }

  void touchEnded(TouchData touch) {
    //touch ended code here
    taps.removeWhere((element) => element.touchId == touch.touchId);
  }
}

///Every touch point must have the touch id, here touch id will be every offset on the screen
///until finger has not left i.e., until drag doesn't end.
class TouchData {
  final int touchId;
  final Offset offset;

  TouchData(this.touchId, this.offset);
}

class ItemDrag extends Drag {
  final Function onUpdate;
  final Function onEnd;
  final Function onCancel;
  final int touchId;

  ItemDrag(this.onUpdate, this.onEnd, this.onCancel, this.touchId);

  @override
  void update(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    super.update(details);
    onUpdate(details, touchId);
  }

  @override
  void end(DragEndDetails details) {
    super.end(details);
    onEnd(details, touchId);
  }

  @override
  void cancel() {
    super.cancel();
    onCancel(touchId);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful. I appreciate it. How could one modify this to only work when the initial touch is on the square? For now, this code allows the 3 fingers to be anywhere on the screen and it moves the square there.

Comment: Thats tricky, but you can try to get offset of first Tap from the list of tap and before enabling drag check if that offset lies in the square, you can get the rect from the widgets renderobject

Comment: Awesome I will give that a go! The last thing is with the above code, it always jumps a little bit down and left before it moves, would there be a reason for that or a way to fix it?

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems ImmediateMultiDragGestureRecognizer works with globalPosition only. In DragUpdateDetails both properties (globalPos/localPos) have the same value, which is incorrect.
While MultiTapGestureRecognizer for the same widget emits TapDownDetails with both local/global positions correctly handled.